# How to simplify type casting in Java

Tags: java, reflection, coding-style

I have a reflection utility. This class is implemented to casting the values of certain fields obtained through reflection.

I give the code:

```
/**
 * Get the field values with the types already listed according to the field type
 *
 * @param clazz clazz
 * @param fieldName fieldName
 * @param fieldValue fieldValue
 * @return value cast to specific field type
 */
public static Object castFieldValue(Class<?> clazz, String fieldName, Object fieldValue) {
    Field field = getField(clazz, fieldName)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot find field name:" + fieldName));

    Class<?> fieldType = field.getType();

    if (fieldType.isAssignableFrom(Double.class)) {
        if (fieldValue instanceof String) {
            return Double.valueOf((String)fieldValue);
        }
        return ((Number) fieldValue).doubleValue();
    }

    if (fieldType.isAssignableFrom(Long.class)) {
        if (fieldValue instanceof String) {
            return Long.valueOf((String)fieldValue);
        }
        return ((Number) fieldValue).longValue();
    }

    if (fieldType.isAssignableFrom(Float.class)) {
        if (fieldValue instanceof String) {
            return Float.valueOf((String)fieldValue);
        }
        return ((Number) fieldValue).floatValue();
    }

    if (fieldType.isAssignableFrom(Integer.class)) {
        if (fieldValue instanceof String) {
            return Integer.valueOf((String)fieldValue);
        }
        return ((Number) fieldValue).intValue();
    }

    if (fieldType.isAssignableFrom(Short.class)) {
        if (fieldValue instanceof String) {
            return Short.valueOf((String)fieldValue);
        }
        return ((Number) fieldValue).shortValue();
    }

    return fieldValue;
}

public static Optional<Field> getField(Class<?> clazz, String fieldName) {
    Field[] fields = getAllFields(clazz);
    return Stream.of(fields)
            .filter(x -> x.getName().equals(fieldName))
            .findFirst();
}

public static Field[] getAllFields(Class<?> clazz) {
    if (clazz == null) return null;

    List<Field> fields = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(clazz.getDeclaredFields()));
    if (clazz.getSuperclass() != null) {
        // danger! Recursion
        fields.addAll(Arrays.asList(getAllFields(clazz.getSuperclass())));
    }
    return fields.toArray(new Field[] {});
}
```

This code is very verbose. Is it possible to simplify it somehow?

It is this piece of code that is repeated many times with minor changes:

```
if (fieldType.isAssignableFrom(Short.class)) {
    if (fieldValue instanceof String) {
        return Short.valueOf((String)fieldValue);
    }
    return ((Number) fieldValue).shortValue();
}
```

If I clarify once again what my method does, it leads to the correct type of value in accordance with the type of the class field.

Comment: Where does `fieldValue` come from? If it comes from e.g. `clazz.getField(fieldName).get(...)`, then the work the method is doing is pointless and you can remove it completely. Otherwise, I don't understand what the method is supposed to be doing, and you should [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54843811/edit) to more clearly explain its purpose.

Comment: From what I can tell, this method creates a new type from a string.  If the field type is `Short` then the string is parsed and returned as a `Short`.  If the field type is `Float` then the string is parsed and a `Float` type is returned.  There's some odd error trapping and other conventions that don't seem to be mentioned in the Java doc, but that appears to be the jist of it.

Comment: @kai I do this for the dynamic query of the Hibernate Criteria. And there you need to substitute the value that will match the type of the field. Therefore, I return just the Object

Comment: take the last coment back - you have longs... But you could use stringformat to get a Number. With that you could eliminate the inner if in the ifcascade. But thats cosmetic at best...

Comment: Also you could retrieve the constructor from the class and construct the object.  All numbers(Double, Float, Long, Integer ) have constructors for String . https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#Double-java.lang.String-

Comment: I'm a little confused.  Hibernate is an ORM.  Shouldn't your ORM be doing this kind of coercion for you?